# How can I read struct elements from file?

Tags: c

Hi I have the following structure:

```
struct points{
    int round[11];
    int sum;
};

struct student{
    char studid[7];
    char *s_name;
    char *f_name;
    struct points p_points;
};
```

I am creating an array of structures, each representing an individual student. When I exit my program I will save that array to a file using the following function:

```
int save_file(struct student *array, int size, const char *filename){
    struct student *object=malloc(size*sizeof(struct student));
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        object[i].f_name=malloc(strlen(array[0].etunimi)+1);
        object[i].s_name=malloc(strlen(array[0].sukunimi+1));
        strcpy(object[i].f_name,array[0].etunimi);
        strcpy(object[i].s_name,array[0].sukunimi);
        strcpy(object[i].studid,array[0].opnro);
        object[i].points=array[0].points;
    }
    FILE * file= fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (file != NULL) {
        fwrite(object, size*sizeof(struct student), 1, file);
        fclose(file);
    }
    for(int x=0;x<size;x++){
        free(object[x].etunimi);
        free(object[x].sukunimi);
    }
    free(object);
    return 1;
}
```

When I want to modify the record and load the file I am facing a problem. I don't know how to allocate memory for object[i].f_name and object[i].s_name and I don't know the size of the array in the file. My function looks like this now:

```
int read_file(const char *filename){
    struct student *object2=malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    FILE * file= fopen("output", "rb");
    if (file != NULL) {
        fread(object2, sizeof(struct student), 1, file);
        fclose(file);
    }
    print_situation(object2,1);
    return 1;
}
```

How can I check the size of the array in the file and get the lengths of f_name and s_name from the file in order to allocate the memory properly?

Comment: There's no quick fix. You need to input the data (fgets is the easiest way), then parse it, determine the length of any strings or other variable-length fields, and call malloc to set up the variable structures.

Comment: Your output routine doesn't work anyway, as it won't be writing out the strings pointed at by `f_name` and `s_name` - it'll be outputting the memory location, which will be meaningless when you come to read the data back in.

Comment: Why are you malloc'ing in your save routine?  Seems like you can simply write out each student without copying to a temporary structure.  If you write out the string terminators '\0' then you can determine the string sizes when reading them back in.